# insert(item) in a rooted tree - LCRS representation

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, abstraction

Below is the code,

```
/* tree.c */
#include"tree.h"

int main(){
  Tree *rootedTree = newTree();
  insert(rootedTree, "~jrs/61b");
  preOrder(rootedTree);
  printf("\n");
}
```

---

```
/* tree.h */
#include<stddef.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct SiblingTreeNode{
  struct SiblingTreeNode *parent;
  void *item;
  struct SiblingTreeNode *firstChild;
  struct SiblingTreeNode *nextSibling;
}Node;

typedef struct LCRSTree{
  Node *root;
  int size;
}Tree;


Tree * newTree(void){
  Tree *rootedTree = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
  rootedTree->root = NULL;
  rootedTree->size = 0;
  return rootedTree;
}

void insert(Tree *rootedTree, const void *item){
  if(rootedTree->root == NULL){

    Node *rootNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    rootNode->parent = NULL;
    rootNode->item = malloc(sizeof(strlen((const char *)item) + 1));
    strcpy((char *)rootNode->item, (const char *)item);
    rootNode->firstChild = NULL;
    rootNode->nextSibling = NULL;

    rootedTree->root = rootNode;
    rootedTree->size = 0;
  }else{
    /*
       Who takes care of the ordering of inserting items?
       User or insert() function?
    */
  }
}

void visit(Node *node){
  printf("\n(%s)", (char *)(node->item));
}
/*
  Pre-order traversal.

  Visit each node before recursively visiting its children, left to right.
  Root visited first
*/
void preOrderTraverse(Node * node){
  visit(node);
  if(node->firstChild){
    printf("\n|");
    preOrderTraverse(node->firstChild);
  }
  if(node->nextSibling){
    printf("-->");
    preOrderTraverse(node->nextSibling);
  }
}
void preOrder(Tree *tree){
  preOrderTraverse(tree->root);
}
```

---

for rooted tree using [LCRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree) representation.

Using `Tree` abstraction, if I need to build a tree, like shown below, where `cs61b` course details have been maintained,

[image]
My below question is about, how to `insert` items in rooted tree?

With `insert()` function taking `Tree` and `item` as parameters, it is easy (obvious) to `insert()` item `"~jrs/61b"`

What is the order of `insert()`ing `firstChild` and `nextSibling` items in `rootedTree`? Does two given parameters of `insert()` suffice?

For example, Do I need to `insert()`, `"hw1"` & `"hw2"` after `"hw"`? or Do I need to `insert()`, `"index.html"` immediately after `insert()`ing `"hw"`?

or

Do I need to maintain separate functions for inserting `item` as next sibling and first child?

*Note: Not asking for code. Learning Trees*

Comment: There's at least one `}` missing in the code (`void visit(Node *node){` is embedded inside `void insert()`).  If you're deliberately using the GCC extension of nested functions, say so — they are totally non-standard C and not widely used and should be explicitly called out to prevent comments like this from being necessary.  If you're not, then you should post compilable code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I compiled and copied from `emacs` editor to this site. Am sure, Copy paste error, I missed closed brace of `insert`. `visit` is outside `insert`. I never used nested functions in C. Anyways edited and added the close brace. BTW, Nice to see you after a gap.

Comment: The 'who takes care of the ordering of siblings' is up to the person who writes the code that maintains the tree.  You might take the view that new items are always inserted as the 'first child', or always appended as the 'last sibling', or you might decide that the items in a sibling list should appear in some order — for example, if the `item` is a string, then in a sorted order of the names in the strings.  All of those are valid; not all of them are necessarily what you want.

Comment: Why is the root tree size 0 and not 1 after inserting the root node?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Because `insert()` method is incomplete. Am yet to decide, where to set `size` in the `insert` code. Can be common code.  But, definitely I missed.

Comment: Note that if you're encoding a path such as `~jrs/61b/hw/hw1`, the code has to know the significance of the path separator (`/`) and how to handle sub-directories, etc. That means analyzing the data, I think, and making sure that the correct intermediate nodes exist (creating `~jrs/61b/hw` if you create `~jrs/61/hw/hw1` immediately after inserting the root node. We can debate whether that means that you should have `~jrs` as the root node and `61b` as its first child, etc. (I've not played with LCRS trees; I'm going on the basis of what's in your diagram and … let's call it common sense.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Just for my info,Which representations you generally use for rooted trees? multi walk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130742/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-overexchange).

Answer (score 0):

> With `insert()` function taking `Tree` and `item` as parameters, …
>   Does two given parameters of `insert()` suffice?

No, they don't suffice, since the tree structure cannot be deduced from an *order of `insert()`ing*.

> Do I need to maintain separate functions for inserting `item` as next sibling and first child?

Yes, or something equivalent, like a parameter which tells how to insert. Also the node where to append the new item will be needed as a parameter.